# Give a file with another delimiter, not a comma, into Solr's SimplePOSTTool

Tags: solr

I have many CSV's I've uploaded into Solr with it's SimplePOSTTool, but now I have a file that is separated by a pipe (|). Is there a way too upload that as is? And have it read as "pipe separated values"?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the separator used for CSV files through the `separator=|` argument in the URL. See [Uploading Data with Index Handlers - CSV Formatted Index Updates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-CSVFormattedIndexUpdates) in the documentation for the full argument list.

> **separator** Character used as field separator; default is ","

You can also use this on a per-field basis if you have a field that's internally delimited by a different character and want to index it as a multivalued field into a single field name by prefixing the value with `f.fieldname.separator=` instead.

Comment: A problem is my extensions are .txt so when I have `filetype csv` it doesn't find any of the files.

Comment: @bzupnick Change the extension?